# HTML - String containing color codes to color

Tags: php, html

I'm currently facing a problem here, I have many different strings like these:

```
"he#00ff00llo"
"#cc9200test"
```

And so on.

I'm outputting this on an HTML page (Grabbing it through my database)
Anyways, what I want to achieve is to read those #00ff00 and output it as the color itself.

**EDIT:**

these are usernames, and most of the time they go like this: #ff0000#SomeName | Which I then want to turn into `<span style="color: #ff0000">#SomeName</span>` oh and the there are usernames with several colorcodes.

**EDIT:**

My friend gave me this code which solved my problem. :)
**IT WAS SOLVED IN PHP**
**ALSO THE CODE BELOW (Posted by Oriol) IS WORKING! :)**
**THIS CODE WORKS(PHP):**

```
<?php
function colorCodesRenderProperly($name)
{
    $name = htmlspecialchars($name);
    if(preg_match('/^(#[0-9a-fA-F]{6})+$/', $name) === 1)
    {
        return $name;
    }
    preg_match_all('/#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}/', $name, $codes);
    $replaced = array();
    $codes_original = $codes;
    $i = 0;
    $count = 1;
    foreach($codes[0] as &$code)
    {
        if(in_array($codes_original[0][$i], $replaced))
        {
            continue;
        }
        $code = sprintf('%02s', dechex((hexdec($code[1].$code[2])/255*128)))
            .sprintf('%02s', dechex((hexdec($code[3].$code[4])/255*128)))
            .sprintf('%02s', dechex((hexdec($code[5].$code[6])/255*128)));
        $name = str_replace($codes_original[0][$i], "<span style=\"color: #$code;\">", $name, $count);
        $replaced[] = $codes_original[0][$i];
        $i++;
        $count = 1;
    }
    while($i > 0)
    {
        $name .= "</span>";
        $i--;
    }
    return $name;
}
?>
```

Comment: Ok cool. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking.  Do you want the output of these two strings to be "hegreenllo" and "yellowtest"?

Comment: @hd Well, to be honest I've been Googling a lot, but haven't seem to found the answer. Oh and I'm not very experienced in HTML. | Mark: basically, I want the color codes to display the color. So obviously #ff0000Test would be (RED TEXT)Test :)

Comment: Also do you need the words with in each string to be in that color? exp. "Hello" in one color and "test" in another?

Comment: @user3841730 Maybe I should rephrase. What **code** have you tried so far?

Comment: @hd. Well, as I said, I'm not very experienced with HTML so I haven't tried any code; as I said I have been Googling but found no solutions. :)

Comment: What do you mean by "color" do you want the RGB?

Comment: Do you know there are hex colors which have no name? What do you want to do with these? Does all your hex colors have 6 digits, or do you also have 3 digit color?

Comment: @greaterKing Mmm, like "c#ff0000oo#0000ffl" would turn into: c<span style="color:#ff0000">oo</span><span style="color:#0000ff">l</span> maybe?

Comment: http://bavotasan.com/2011/convert-hex-color-to-rgb-using-php/ this converts hex to rbg

Comment: @Oriol 6 characters/digits on every :)

Comment: @Wabonano I appreciate your help, but this is not what I'm trying to achieve. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var txt = document.createTextNode("he#00ff00llo"),
    wrapper = document.createElement('span'),
    regExp = /#[\da-f]{6}/i,
    pos;
wrapper.appendChild(txt);
while(~(pos = txt.nodeValue.search(regExp))) {
    txt = txt.splitText(pos);
    var span = wrapper.cloneNode(false);
    span.style.color = txt.nodeValue.substr(0,7);
    txt.nodeValue = txt.nodeValue.substr(7);
    span.appendChild(txt);
    wrapper.appendChild(span);
}
// append wrapper to the DOM
```